# How to remove super glue from prescription eye-glasses lens

Tags: cleaning, glass, eyeglasses

I have a problem, I need to remove a drop of super glue on the lens of my glasses without scratching them.

Also, these are not glass lenses, (think the impact/scratch proof material)

Comment: Is it on the glass part of your glasses or the frame? And are the glasses glass and do they have a non-glass layer on top? Or is it on the frame on a part that does not show as much?

Comment: it is on the glass part, and my glasses are not from glass hhh, and ot they didn't have the non-glass layer

Comment: What size is the drop of super glue? Also, on what side did it land?  Inside? (Towards your eye) or outside? (Away from eye?) It may be relevant for tooling choice, and the size will tell us if a thermal chemical or mechanical solution is required. or even possible. A picture of the glasses would help a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Put your glasses in the freezer overnight. This will make the glue brittle and easy to scrape off with a fingernail.

Comment: thank you for responding, but I tested and it doesn't work,

Comment: Good answer! If the material is a hard resin it will contract faster than the crystallized drop, but that will only work on a relatively large drop (wider than it's height) . Will work I best on glass made lenses. Polymer resin  based lenses will bond strongly with cyanoacrylate (super glue) so the last option is to apply a solvent that will quicken the super glue yet sparing the resin substrate of the lens. It's a tall order!

Answer (score 2):

Super glue isn't waterproof - it nearly is, but not quite.

if you soak in water, it should eventually come loose with no damage at all.
It might take some perseverance, as it is nearly waterproof, but eventually you will win.

If the surface is truly glass, you could scrape it off with a razor blade, but not if they're plastic.